# Phpunit Error - failed asserting node denoted by

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-test

I am using PHPUnit 3.5.x along with Zend 1.10
I have a line in my IndexControllerTestCase.php

```
$this->assertXpathContentContains("id('message')", "test message");
```

this shows an error

```
1) IndexControllerTest::testIndexWithMessageAction
Failed asserting node denoted by id CONTAINS content "test message"

C:\xampp\htdocs\hive\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Constraint\DomQuery.php:256
C:\xampp\htdocs\hive\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\ControllerTestCase.php:516
C:\xampp\htdocs\testsample\tests\application\controllers\IndexControllerTest.php
:14
```

Any idea why this error pops up? Any help would really be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no XPath wizard, but in our tests we use something like the following to look for the <div> with the `id` of `message`.

```
$this->assertXpathContentContains('//div[@id="message"]', "test message");
```